# User still cannot see database tables in SSMS after GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [Login]

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Ive created a login, created them as a user with db_datareader in a DatabaseA and then granted view any definition to the login.

The user still cannot see the tables in the database in SSMS.

I done the same on DatabaseB, and it worked as expected.
Appreciate thoughts on what might be preventing the user seeing tables in database

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [myLogin] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
USE [DatabaseA]
GO
CREATE USER [myLogin] FOR LOGIN [myLogin]
GO
USE [DatabaseA]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [myLogin]
GO

use master 
go
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [myLogin]

----------------------------------------

GO
USE [DatabaseB]
GO
CREATE USER [myLogin] FOR LOGIN [myLogin]
GO
USE [DatabaseB]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [myLogin]
GO

use master 
go
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [myLogin]
```

Comment: @BogdanSahlean refresh did not work, i also had them log out and back in but it did not work either.

Comment: Does [`sp_HelpRotect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helprotect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) return anything interesting for `DatabaseA`? (Shall we all chip in to buy some "p" for Microsoft?)

Comment: @HABO sp_Helprotect returns nothing except the message "there are no matching rows on which to report". I have also checked sys.database_permissions and the only explicit "deny" are on execution of procedures.  The database in question is at compatibility level 120 (2014), but the database server is 14 (2017), could that cause an issue?

Comment: Is there any illuminating data in either sys.login_token or sys.user_token for the login and that login's user in the database (respectively)? If you're able to impersonate the login, it's relatively simple to select from those two views under impersonation.

Comment: Reading up on this, there seem to be some issues w/ the VIEW ANY DEFINITION permission. Beyond needing a user in the db, sometimes it just doesn't seem to work properly. If you grant that permission inside the database(s) needed, does it work? Could be a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: @BenThul no, i cannot see anything strange wrt the login. I can reproduce this with multiple logins also, so i dont think its a login issue.

Comment: @PeterSchott  i just tried going into the database, finding the user and granting them view definition on each table. although the action didnt throw an error, the permissions were not applied and they user still cannot see any tables.

Comment: @wilson_smyth - if you can reproduce with multiple logins, that would suggest to me that there's an issue with something that all of those logins share. For example, the `public` role, an AD group they have in common, etc. Honestly, having multiples is a gift for troubleshooting.